# SSIS ADO NET source error with wide table

Tags: ssis

I am using ADO NET source in SSIS, I have table with 5mio rows and 60 columns. Task status is completed without errors but only for 245k rows. I reduced columns to 30 and task i completed for all 5mio rows.
Do you know what is the problem with wide tables?

Comment: You need to provide more info than you have before anyone can help e.g. what is your SSIS task doing, can you provide the relevant part of the log, what have you done so far to troubleshoot and investigate?

Comment: There is no problem with wide tables.   Maybe the problem is in one of the specific columns that you removed.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

[image]

Target table has 100 columns

```
CREATE TABLE 
    dbo.so_35450935
(
    col1 int NOT NULL
,   col2 int NOT NULL
,   col3 int NOT NULL
,   col4 int NOT NULL
,   col5 int NOT NULL
,   col6 int NOT NULL
,   col7 int NOT NULL
,   col8 int NOT NULL
,   col9 int NOT NULL
,   col10 int NOT NULL
,   col11 int NOT NULL
,   col12 int NOT NULL
,   col13 int NOT NULL
,   col14 int NOT NULL
,   col15 int NOT NULL
,   col16 int NOT NULL
,   col17 int NOT NULL
,   col18 int NOT NULL
,   col19 int NOT NULL
,   col20 int NOT NULL
,   col21 int NOT NULL
,   col22 int NOT NULL
,   col23 int NOT NULL
,   col24 int NOT NULL
,   col25 int NOT NULL
,   col26 int NOT NULL
,   col27 int NOT NULL
,   col28 int NOT NULL
,   col29 int NOT NULL
,   col30 int NOT NULL
,   col31 int NOT NULL
,   col32 int NOT NULL
,   col33 int NOT NULL
,   col34 int NOT NULL
,   col35 int NOT NULL
,   col36 int NOT NULL
,   col37 int NOT NULL
,   col38 int NOT NULL
,   col39 int NOT NULL
,   col40 int NOT NULL
,   col41 int NOT NULL
,   col42 int NOT NULL
,   col43 int NOT NULL
,   col44 int NOT NULL
,   col45 int NOT NULL
,   col46 int NOT NULL
,   col47 int NOT NULL
,   col48 int NOT NULL
,   col49 int NOT NULL
,   col50 int NOT NULL
,   col51 int NOT NULL
,   col52 int NOT NULL
,   col53 int NOT NULL
,   col54 int NOT NULL
,   col55 int NOT NULL
,   col56 int NOT NULL
,   col57 int NOT NULL
,   col58 int NOT NULL
,   col59 int NOT NULL
,   col60 int NOT NULL
,   col61 int NOT NULL
,   col62 int NOT NULL
,   col63 int NOT NULL
,   col64 int NOT NULL
,   col65 int NOT NULL
,   col66 int NOT NULL
,   col67 int NOT NULL
,   col68 int NOT NULL
,   col69 int NOT NULL
,   col70 int NOT NULL
,   col71 int NOT NULL
,   col72 int NOT NULL
,   col73 int NOT NULL
,   col74 int NOT NULL
,   col75 int NOT NULL
,   col76 int NOT NULL
,   col77 int NOT NULL
,   col78 int NOT NULL
,   col79 int NOT NULL
,   col80 int NOT NULL
,   col81 int NOT NULL
,   col82 int NOT NULL
,   col83 int NOT NULL
,   col84 int NOT NULL
,   col85 int NOT NULL
,   col86 int NOT NULL
,   col87 int NOT NULL
,   col88 int NOT NULL
,   col89 int NOT NULL
,   col90 int NOT NULL
,   col91 int NOT NULL
,   col92 int NOT NULL
,   col93 int NOT NULL
,   col94 int NOT NULL
,   col95 int NOT NULL
,   col96 int NOT NULL
,   col97 int NOT NULL
,   col98 int NOT NULL
,   col99 int NOT NULL
,   col100 int NOT NULL
);
```

Source Query puts 5 million rows into that table

```
SELECT TOP 5000000
    0 AS col1 
,   1 AS col2 
,   2 AS col3 
,   3 AS col4 
,   4 AS col5 
,   5 AS col6 
,   6 AS col7 
,   7 AS col8 
,   8 AS col9 
,   9 AS col10 
,   10 AS col11 
,   11 AS col12 
,   12 AS col13 
,   13 AS col14 
,   14 AS col15 
,   15 AS col16 
,   16 AS col17 
,   17 AS col18 
,   18 AS col19 
,   19 AS col20 
,   20 AS col21 
,   21 AS col22 
,   22 AS col23 
,   23 AS col24 
,   24 AS col25 
,   25 AS col26 
,   26 AS col27 
,   27 AS col28 
,   28 AS col29 
,   29 AS col30 
,   30 AS col31 
,   31 AS col32 
,   32 AS col33 
,   33 AS col34 
,   34 AS col35 
,   35 AS col36 
,   36 AS col37 
,   37 AS col38 
,   38 AS col39 
,   39 AS col40 
,   40 AS col41 
,   41 AS col42 
,   42 AS col43 
,   43 AS col44 
,   44 AS col45 
,   45 AS col46 
,   46 AS col47 
,   47 AS col48 
,   48 AS col49 
,   49 AS col50 
,   50 AS col51 
,   51 AS col52 
,   52 AS col53 
,   53 AS col54 
,   54 AS col55 
,   55 AS col56 
,   56 AS col57 
,   57 AS col58 
,   58 AS col59 
,   59 AS col60 
,   60 AS col61 
,   61 AS col62 
,   62 AS col63 
,   63 AS col64 
,   64 AS col65 
,   65 AS col66 
,   66 AS col67 
,   67 AS col68 
,   68 AS col69 
,   69 AS col70 
,   70 AS col71 
,   71 AS col72 
,   72 AS col73 
,   73 AS col74 
,   74 AS col75 
,   75 AS col76 
,   76 AS col77 
,   77 AS col78 
,   78 AS col79 
,   79 AS col80 
,   80 AS col81 
,   81 AS col82 
,   82 AS col83 
,   83 AS col84 
,   84 AS col85 
,   85 AS col86 
,   86 AS col87 
,   87 AS col88 
,   88 AS col89 
,   89 AS col90 
,   90 AS col91 
,   91 AS col92 
,   92 AS col93 
,   93 AS col94 
,   94 AS col95 
,   95 AS col96 
,   96 AS col97 
,   97 AS col98 
,   98 AS col99 
,   99 AS col100 
FROM
    sys.all_columns AC
    CROSS APPLY
    sys.all_columns AC2
    CROSS APPLY
    sys.all_columns AC3;
```

Biml to reproduce my package

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <AdoNetConnection Name="tempdb" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Database=tempdb;" Provider="SQL"  />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_35450935">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="RowCountSource">0</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Works Fine">
                    <Transformations>
                        <AdoNetSource ConnectionName="tempdb" Name="ADOSRC Generate 5M rows">
                            <DirectInput><![CDATA[SELECT TOP 5000000
    0 AS col1 
,   1 AS col2 
,   2 AS col3 
,   3 AS col4 
,   4 AS col5 
,   5 AS col6 
,   6 AS col7 
,   7 AS col8 
,   8 AS col9 
,   9 AS col10 
,   10 AS col11 
,   11 AS col12 
,   12 AS col13 
,   13 AS col14 
,   14 AS col15 
,   15 AS col16 
,   16 AS col17 
,   17 AS col18 
,   18 AS col19 
,   19 AS col20 
,   20 AS col21 
,   21 AS col22 
,   22 AS col23 
,   23 AS col24 
,   24 AS col25 
,   25 AS col26 
,   26 AS col27 
,   27 AS col28 
,   28 AS col29 
,   29 AS col30 
,   30 AS col31 
,   31 AS col32 
,   32 AS col33 
,   33 AS col34 
,   34 AS col35 
,   35 AS col36 
,   36 AS col37 
,   37 AS col38 
,   38 AS col39 
,   39 AS col40 
,   40 AS col41 
,   41 AS col42 
,   42 AS col43 
,   43 AS col44 
,   44 AS col45 
,   45 AS col46 
,   46 AS col47 
,   47 AS col48 
,   48 AS col49 
,   49 AS col50 
,   50 AS col51 
,   51 AS col52 
,   52 AS col53 
,   53 AS col54 
,   54 AS col55 
,   55 AS col56 
,   56 AS col57 
,   57 AS col58 
,   58 AS col59 
,   59 AS col60 
,   60 AS col61 
,   61 AS col62 
,   62 AS col63 
,   63 AS col64 
,   64 AS col65 
,   65 AS col66 
,   66 AS col67 
,   67 AS col68 
,   68 AS col69 
,   69 AS col70 
,   70 AS col71 
,   71 AS col72 
,   72 AS col73 
,   73 AS col74 
,   74 AS col75 
,   75 AS col76 
,   76 AS col77 
,   77 AS col78 
,   78 AS col79 
,   79 AS col80 
,   80 AS col81 
,   81 AS col82 
,   82 AS col83 
,   83 AS col84 
,   84 AS col85 
,   85 AS col86 
,   86 AS col87 
,   87 AS col88 
,   88 AS col89 
,   89 AS col90 
,   90 AS col91 
,   91 AS col92 
,   92 AS col93 
,   93 AS col94 
,   94 AS col95 
,   95 AS col96 
,   96 AS col97 
,   97 AS col98 
,   98 AS col99 
,   99 AS col100 
FROM
    sys.all_columns AC
    CROSS APPLY
    sys.all_columns AC2
    CROSS APPLY
    sys.all_columns AC3;]]></DirectInput>
                        </AdoNetSource>
                        <RowCount VariableName="User.RowCountSource" Name="CNT SourceRows" />
                        <AdoNetDestination ConnectionName="tempdb" Name="ADODST dbo_so_35450935">
                            <ExternalTableOutput Table="[dbo].[so_35450935]" />
                        </AdoNetDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```